# ImportError: No module named abc

Tags: python, import

I created a class named abc in the python26 folder. I tried to refer it through another file

```
def FileRW():
   import re
   import os
   import abc
```

I am getting error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    FileRW()
  File "C:\Python26\pyFileIOprog", line 4, in FileRW
    import ChangeList
ImportError: No module named abc

Could anybody please tell me as where I am going wrong. I have setup environment variables 'path' to C:\python26

Comment: This is probably better at superuser. However, python uses the variable PYTHONPATH. Check that you have that variable set.

Comment: (a) don't put your own code in the Python folder, put it in your own project folder (in fact, make it a virtualenv); and (b) `abc` is a standard module name. Try to avoid reusing such names, it causes confusion.

Comment: I tried to use fill the PYTHONPATH variable with value C:\Python26;C:\Python26\DLLs;C:\Python26\LIB;C:\Python26\LIB\LIB-TK I got error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    FileRW()
  File "C:\Python26\pyFileIOprog", line 4, in FileRW
    import abc
ImportError: No module named abc

Answer (score 3):

`abc` is the name of a standard library module distributed with Python, so I strongly suggest you change the name to something that is unique.

Assuming you've done that, you can either put the module's file(s) in the same directory as the script that imports it and it will be found. If you want to put it somewhere else, you can append the path to its location to the `sys.path` variable. Here's an example:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/my/module')
# on Windows append something like 'C:\\path\\to\\my\\module' or r'C:\path\to\my\module'  

import my_abc  # should work now

...
```

Note that the above won't work unless you change the module's name because Python will find the standard module before it looks in the directory path you've appended. You could override that by inserting your module's path at the beginning of the `sys.path` list, but again I don't recommend doing that.

If you'd like your module's path automatically appended to the system's module search path, you can create a *name*.pth file and put it in one of four special directories. See the online documentation for the [`site.py`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html?highlight=pth) file for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is called `abc.py` then it's going to try to import itself and therefore raise an `ImportError` because of the circular dependency. Try to be careful not to name your program files the same names as modules in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. My project was using pymongo module in python2 and this pymongo internally uses the abc library. I tried lot of solution and searched a lot but none of the solution worked out.  So I planned to re-installed or remove the python completely from my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.  But sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7  command was also failing and was throwing same abc module not found error.  So I finally Did few hacks and cracks. Here are the steps -

Removing all python version manually

- sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python2.x as well as python3.x
- sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.x as well as python3.x
- sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.x as well as python 3.x

Updating Ubuntu

- sudo apt-get update

In Between if you get this error **The package  needs to be reinstalled ubuntu** Then  Run following command

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And delete all the lines from above file for the package above package_name

Now download a python tgz file from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and unzip it and CD into it

```
./configure
make test
sudo make install
```

Python should be installed now.  Check by running python

Answer (score -2):

Is abc a module (abc.py) or a package (abd directory)?

In any case, check they exist in the same directory as pyFileIOprog

Comment: `abc` is a standard library module.

Comment: oh... sorry... I just thought you were using a fake module name.

Comment: abc is module. I think of it to be a class defined in separate file.